# "Community"-deleted question policy is overly strict

Tags: discussion, automatic-deletion

The "Community" user deletion of questions ("roomba") is overly strict.  I'm specifically referring to [this rule set](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba):

> If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked

And, how it was applied to this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57962098/handling-specific-content-type-in-chrome-extension ([cached link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57962098/handling-specific-content-type-in-chrome-extension) for <10k users).

For domain-specific questions, it's entirely likely that many days will go by before an answer turns up.  It's unsafe to assume that an unanswered question is unanswerable after only 30 days.  Perhaps this works for popular broad topics, but it does not work for more narrowly focused topics.

I also don't think that a single downvote should be enough to trigger this action.  It would be different if there were several, but that's not the case here.  (Additionally, in my specific case, I have a hunch that some user is messing with me, as every few days a small handful of my recent questions all get downvotes at the same time.  I couldn't care less about the reputation or whatever, but auto-deleting questions is frustrating.  Even if the downvote issue were somehow fixed though, I still think this policy auto-delete should be improved for other users.)

Finally, I was in the process of adding a bounty to this question when I saw that it was auto-deleted.  Perhaps other users would appreciate the opportunity to add a bounty before this auto-delete action occurs due to any reason.

Please reconsider this policy.

**Edit:**  After discussion with @Tom, here are some specific proposals:

- Roomba should notify or comment a week or so before it takes any action.  This gives users an opportunity to edit their question to improve it, or to start a bounty.
- Ensure Roomba doesn't affect questions with an active bounty
- Consider setting the score for Roomba to `-2`, (down from `-1` where it is today)

Comment: I don't know... In one hand I understand and even felt the same myself recently on one of my questions that received supsicious downvotes before being auto deleted, in the other hand I also feel it is actually needed for numerous abandoned questions. Isn't the *undelete* feature enough to handle false positives?

Comment: @Kaiido If there were multiple downvotes, I would totally agree with you.  In this case, it's just a single vote.

Comment: *"Automatically re-open questions if a user starts a bounty on them."*: offering a bounty on a closed question (or even deleted) isn't possible right now. This feature-request is discussed here: [Give bounty to an answer in a closed question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391370)

Comment: @Tom Maybe the simplest thing then is just to have Roomba leave a comment (or notification?  not sure how this works...) days before it does whatever it's going to do, giving users a poke to edit their question (the usually-required case), or to start a bounty (for cases like mine).

Comment: That's honestly a pretty good idea, I like that. If then someone still doesn't act on their question, then it would be really dead/abandoned. Can you add that to the list of possible solutions?

Answer (score 6):

As often happens, [Shog's advice is good advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310266/348149): just re-ask the question.

In a case like this, all other options take much more work and are unnecessary.

Add whatever additional details you’ve learned since the question was originally posted to the new question. Practically, there are always things that can be done to improve a post.

Then, in a couple of days, you’ll be able to post a bounty on a fresher and hopefully improved question.

Roomba is quite conservative already, and you have all the tools to sidestep this particular edge case if you believe it’s worth it.

Asking it again is not adding "clutter" or noise. The first one is deleted, so it's not adding to the noise. It's effectively gone.

And, of course, if the first question was deleted via delete votes of any kind, or if it were closed as off-topic, this wouldn't be acting like a good site citizen. But this is not the case.

On the other hand, making Roomba even more conservative, as you propose, **would add clutter and noise to the site**. The vast majority of questions that Roomba takes care of need not remain visible (or to be asked again). This advice is only mean to address the edge cases where the question is worth keeping around.